# I have a table in Postgres, and I want to move it to Hbase

Tags: hbase

I have a table in Postgres,but now Im supposed to implement Hbase as back-end database, so I want to move the table below into Hbase, how to redesign this table? Im quite new to Hbase.

```
id        geom            osm_id         name           type
1  00003381C75CBE6443    24254755   Millenium Hall     office
2  00003382D5B5D76S3G    ...
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transform(redesign) the table in Postgres into Hbase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039830/how-to-transformredesign-the-table-in-postgres-into-hbase)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to move the already present table data from postgres to hbase, save some time and use [sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org). Otherwise, if you want to do it manually , then since hbase has no notion of explicitly defining columns at the time of table creation and it stores data in ByteArray, you can use put command as `put 'table_name','1', 'colfam:geom','00003381C75CBE6443'`. Similarly , do it for every column.

Answer (score -1):

You Need to create a table in hbase with one column family name and all your column will be the part of that column family.

Your id would become the rowkey in hbase.

```
hbase(main):002:0> create 'hbaseTable', 'column1'
0 row(s) in 1.2620 seconds

hbase(main):003:0>
```

where hbaseTable is your name space and column1 will be your table name.
Then after you can save data in hbase table using thrift/native hbase API.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTableInterface table = new HTable(conf, "hbaseTable".getBytes());

Put put = new Put(1.getBytes());// for id 1.
put.add("column1".getBytes(), "geom".getBytes(), 00003381C75CBE6443.getBytes());
put.add("column1".getBytes(), "osm_id".getBytes(), 24254755.getBytes());
put.add("column1".getBytes(), "name".getBytes(), Millenium Hall.getBytes());
put.add("column1".getBytes(), "type".getBytes(), office.getBytes());

puts.add(put);// same can do for other ids as well.


hTable.put(puts);
```